# Final round conflicts in Lancaster

Tags: lancaster

In the final round of Lancaster do you only have to pay a ransom for knights involved in a battle that has been lost twice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you have to pay for *any* captured knights in *any* round (after the first round, obviously), and you fully play through the fifth round before scoring.

If you don't ransom a knight [at some point in the game, in particular the fifth round], that knight will not count towards your knight strength for end-game scoring.